# generate a number exclude some android button click

Tags: android

I'd like to generate numbers in a range. ex from 1 to 10 and don't repeate the ones that had already been generated.

on main activity:

```
int[] ex = {};
Random rnd = new Random();
```

my click button that generate numbers:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String f = from.getText().toString();
            int ff = Integer.parseInt(f);
            String t = to.getText().toString();
            int tt = Integer.parseInt(t);

            int val = getRandomWithExclusion(ff, tt, ex);
            String item = Integer.toString(val);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ex = add(ex, val);
            Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(ex));

        }
```

add is a function to add the generated numbers to ex[]:

```
public static int[] add(int[] initialArray , int newValue) {
    int[] newArray = new int[initialArray.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(initialArray, 0, newArray, 0, initialArray.length);
    newArray[newArray.length - 1] = newValue;
    return newArray;
}
```

**and the function that is not working (it is repeating numbers and after 10 tries (1 to 10 range) it shows a fatal exception:**

```
public int getRandomWithExclusion(int start, int end, int... exclude){
    int rangeLength = end - start - exclude.length;
    int randomInt = rnd.nextInt(rangeLength) + start;

    for (int anExclude : exclude) {
        if (anExclude > randomInt) {
            return randomInt;
        }

        randomInt++;
    }

    return randomInt;
}
```

**why is it repeating the numbers? and why after 10 button clicks (range 1 to 10) it shows an exception**:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a better approach than trying to generate a random number that hasn't already been generated would be to create a list of valid (unique) values and then randomize the list.

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Now the list will be e.g. `[7, 6, 1, 5, 10, 3, 9, 4, 8, 2]` and you can simply iterate over it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! If user would like to generate a number between 1 to 500 for example, in this solution I need to do a for 1 to 500 adding the numbers in the array? Won't it make the app to crash or be slow?

Comment: I would be very surprised if 500 (or even 5000) `String`s slowed your app down. Of course if you used enough of them you could probably crash your app, but I doubt any reasonable number would get you there.

Comment: I just tried with five million `String`s and it took 1.5 seconds to generate the list and another 1.5 seconds to shuffle it. Five hundred strings took 0.5 milliseconds to generate.